# dockerfile install go local packages can be possible?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker image with my golang project. The project has some local packages like *math*:

```
/myproject/
  src/
    main.go
    utils/
      math.go
```

in main.go I include lots of packages but also `math` from *math.go*.

My docker file looks something like:

```
FROM golang:latest

ENV GOPATH=/golib/

RUN /usr/local/go/bin/go get github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

CMD /usr/local/go/bin/go run main.go

EXPOSE 10004
```

How do I include also math package since it's a local package, so it's not deployed on github?

The yml file:

```
services:
    cozonac:
       image: cozonac:local
       ports:
         - "10004:10004"
       volumes:
         - ./src/:/go/
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to ADD or COPY your code into the image. Also, don't use `go run`. That is a toy. Use `go build` or `go install` instead.

Comment: How are you getting `myproject` into your container in the first place?

Comment: I added the yml file for the docker

Comment: @Lucian: if you're mounting the `src` directory as a volume, and you can build the main package, then `utils` is there too. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: The problem is that your volume is not in GOPATH, so Go can't locate the utils package. (There is no math package).

Comment: oh yes, Peter is right. You're putting your code in the default GOPATH, but then changing GOPATH.

Answer (score 1):

You should try below

```
services:
    cozonac:
       image: cozonac:local
       ports:
         - "10004:10004"
       volumes:
         - ./src/:/go/
       environment:
         - GOPATH=/golib/:/go/
```

Just for this case you can append the folder to `GOPATH`

Comment: I fixed it by changing the volume to match my local path:
volumes:
      - ./src/:/usr/local/go/src/gitlab/golang/login/src/ 
And run main.go in dockerfile also from this path